# Is there any way to change intellisense mode in visual studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

It seems `CppProperties.json` will only work for Open Folder project,

I want to do this because I must use clang as the compiler, but intellisense doesn't work
properly when working in clang mode, it work as expected under msvc mode.

By the way, it doesn't work because I'm using boost.

is it possible to change the intellisense mode for normal msbuild C++ project?

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to the following steps to configure a Windows project to use Clang tools:

1. Right-click on the project node in Solution Explorer and choose Properties.
2. Choose All configurations at the top of the dialog. Then, under General > Platform Toolset, choose LLVM (clang-cl).
   [image]
3. After you have set up a Clang configuration, right-click again on the project node and choose Reload project.
4. Visual Studio will provide IntelliSense when it detects that you are using the Clang compiler.

For more information you can see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-msbuild?view=msvc-170).